# random number generation and probability problems

Tags: probability

I recently ran into two problems:

1. given a rand() function that generates 0 and 1 with 50% probability respectively (binary outcome), how to write some code to generate 1 with 90% of the chance and 0 with 10%?
2. There is a society where people will NOT stop having babies until they have a boy. What's the ratio of boys and girls in that society? Consider it's equal probability to have either a boy or a girl.

If possible, please advise what kind of background prob/stats materials these relate to.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand #2.  How can you have *any* babies if you've stopped having them?

Comment: I corrected the description in #2. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your first problem; these are both just pure probability questions.  Let's see if they can find a home on Statistics.SE.

Comment: @DavidMarx: Sorry about that.  I've flagged this question as a duplicate.